# I want to filter on index page location and category of listing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code :

```
def index
if params[:category].blank?
  @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC")
else 
  @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
  @listings = Listing.where(:category_id => @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
 end


if params[:location].blank?
  @listings = Location.all.order("created_at DESC")
else 
  @category_id = Location.find_by(name: params[:location]).id
  @listings = Listing.where(:location_id => @location_id).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

end

Comment: Not totally sure what your question is exactly. Can you include a problem statement? In terms of the code, I don't see where `@location_id` is defined, which will be a problem. I think you mean to define it in the second conditional.... Are you asking for help refactoring this code?

Comment: actually problem is that when i want to find a listing by location , it does not work. only i can find listing by category

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select by a category name or a location name or both, you can apply `where` conditions to the same collection, conditionally.

There's no need to make `category_id` or `location_id` an instance variable unless you want to use them in the view.

Note that the example uses `#try` to retrieve the `id` value from category/location in case no match is found in the Category / Location tables.

```
def index

  @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC")

  if params[:category].present?
    category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).try(:id)
    @listings = @listings.where(category_id: category_id) if category_id
  end

  if params[:location].present?
    location_id = Location.find_by(name: params[:location]).try(:id)
    @listings = @listings.where(location_id: location_id) if location_id
  end

end
```

Comment: This is somewhat flawed. What if both params[:location] and params[:category] are present? `@listings` will be rewritten in the second conditional, and it will only take the location into account... Of course, it's possible that's what the OP would like to do.... We need some clarification on the question.

Comment: No, the `where` clauses are cumulative. Both will be applied to the original collection.  That's why I do the `where` clause on `@listings` not on `Listing`

Comment: Thank you your help .  can you help out with a code for counting and showing number of viewers of post or listing.

Comment: That sounds like you have a new question.  You should post a new question, if so.